# jQuery Mobile app not loading on android

Tags: jquery, cordova

I have created an app using jquery mobile and phonegap. It runs very fine on the android simulator. But when I test it on real device (Samsung galaxy s4, Android 4.3) it loads only the background, but does not show the content.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Adnan

Comment: Can you provide us with your source code or logcat errors.?